# Login Page Redirection

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I had done a Employee Profile in MVC. In a particular screen, i am having 8 tabs. All are working fine. What i need is, if the session expires, the page should be redirected to login page. How to write the JQuery for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var sessionTimeout = 30 * 60; //30 minutes
function toLoginPage() {
   window.location = '/login';
}
setTimeout(toLoginPage, sessionTimeout);
```

or

```
var sessionTimeout = 30 * 60; //30 minutes
setTimeout(function () {
    window.location = '/login';
}, sessionTimeout);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can adapt the logout-function in your account controller to redirect to the login page.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a jquery plug in for idle time out. Follow the link below, it will help you.
http://philpalmieri.com/2009/09/jquery-session-auto-timeout-with-prompt/